# Same Server, Same query, why did I get different query execution time?

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I have made following query to a MySQL server.

```
select ORDER_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,PRICE,AMOUNT,ITEM_ID,ORDER_TIME 
from MY_ORDER order by ORDER_ID desc limit 10000;
```

The `ORDER_ID` is the primary key of the table.

Normally, its almost about 20msec to execute that query (not include fetch time).
But sometime, it took more than 60 msec.

My Question is:
Under the same query, same server, same schema, what could be the reason for such slow execution sometime?

Answer (score 0):

Why different execution times?  There are many *possible* reasons...

Is the table InnoDB?  Or MyISAM?  (My answers may need to change.)

That query possibly hits 100 blocks of data.  Assuming you are using InnoDB, how big is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  If it is not much bigger than 100 blocks (1-2MB), some other process might come along and bump your blocks out of cache, necessitating reload from disk.  Such I/O is significantly slower than reading from cache.

Could another operation on that table, perhaps inserting one row, have come along?  Although InnoDB is very good at allowing multiple threads (connections) to talk to the same table, it sometimes pays a cost in time.

Answer (score -1):

you have to make indexes on Order_id, customer_id, item_id

Comment: I fail to see how this has anything to do with what was asked.